# Processing 10 threads from a ThreadPool at a time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Edit: I am looking for a solution using what is available in .NET 3.5.  I know this is somewhat outdated, but I must stick with it for now.

I have a ThreadPool that I am using to perform about 8 different tasks.  These are all divvied up into different classes, so the don't interfere with each other.  My application is processing about 1300 image files.  All of theme are queued and processed.  However, they all run simultaneously - sometimes hogging all resources or slowing everything down.  I would like to run only x amount of queued items at a time, then wait for them to finish before adding x more to process.

Here is where the image downloading/processing happens.

```
namespace MyNamespace.Threads
{
    public class QueueScanImage : QueueItem
    {
        public QueueScanImage(QueueArgs arg): base(arg)
        {

        }

        public override void Process(object arg)
        {
            Uri urlNext = Args.Link;
            ServerItem server = Args.Server;
            string href = Args.Href;

            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                   //Download file
                   //Process file
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                //Print error to console
            }

            base.Process(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this like this:

```
PoolManager.Enqueue(new QueueScanImage(new QueueArgs(urlNext,server,att.Value)));
```

Ultimately, I would like to do something like this pseudo-code:

```
for(int x = 0; x < #ofThreads-10; x+10)
{
   # Add first 10 queued items to process
   # Wait for all 10 processing items to finish
   # Repeat
}
```

Any help is appreciated, as I'm new to threading in C#.

Comment: I would seriously consider TPL Dataflow...

Comment: You wrote your own ThreadPool? Then the solution is right at hand.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, but I would like some pointers in the right direction.  I don't pretend to know everything about multi-threading in C#, so I'd like to know more.